# Assumptions in Word Problems.

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, derivatives

My dilemma has been that I am confused on how we make mathematical assumptions in WORD problems. Suppose you are given a related-rates word problem.

**(Q#) Air is being pumped into a spherical balloon at a rate of 4.5 cubic feet per minute. Find the rate of change of the radius when the radius is 2 feet.**

My question is how do you figure out if there is a leak located in the balloon? The author doesnt say anything about there being a leak or there NOT being a leak.

**So, how do you determine if there is a hole in the balloon, from which AIR LEAVES?? **
Keep in mind that this is communication. Could it perhaps experience. Because of how you LEARN word problems?

**Or is the answer just that the METHOD of solving word problems is this??**

Thank you very much =)

Answer (score 2):

If there is no stated assumption about air simultaneously leaking, then *assume there is no leak*.

We harvest information given in word problems to solve the problem, **as stated** and neglect possible "what if" situations that are not explicitly described. Sometimes the stated assumptions are idealistic (leaving out possible variations in wind-speed, permeability of material, like the material used to construct a balloon, invariable imperfections in perfect circles, squares, and triangles, etc).

Word problems are constructed and posed so you can have the experience of identifying crucial information and how to use that information to solve the stated problem. Any thing not described explicitly to be taken into consideration in word problem can be omitted from consideration.

Bottom line: Don't make the problem more complicated by trying to cover all possible complications, reasonable, or not.

Comment: Hi, 

That is very good information. But my only question on this is that  WHAT is the **REASON** that you neglect the "What if" statements? DO you do it WITHOUT a specific reason in mind? 
Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that without excluding unstated hypotheses and unstated possibilities, we'd *never* find any satisfying answers, and math could certainly not be applied to any purpose. The list of "what ifs" could persist indefinitely. Answers can be fine-tuned and/or adjusted if we do get more information provided. But we'd never have an answer to fine-tune if we start from the beginning by contemplating what possible complications might exist, and what if this or what if that, and what about...?

Comment: Thanks a bunch =) So is the bottom line the fact that you have to avoid unstated possibilities even though it doesnt have a specific reason?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Comment: -- just a question for you. When you yourself do word problems, do you simply ignore the unstated items WITHOUT any reason? I just want your opinion here =)

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: thanks a lot. I just want to hear a thought from you. Could it perhaps be EXPERIENCE from watching and reading word-problem examples that you believe that nothing besides the givens/stated exists?

Comment: Aakarsh - Experience helps one learn to read and use only the information given in a problem statement, and answer the question *as it is written*. That doesn't mean that things would be so clean in the real world. But word problems are *constructed* in order to test whether students know how to apply what they're learning (using just-introduced methods and/or theorems and/or axioms). They are not designed to test whether you can identify all the possible scenarios and/or real-life unknowns that might have some bearing on the question.

Comment: amWhy, thanks for that. Can you tell me if what I am about to say is correct? Is it a "method of solving word problems" that you assume unstated things dont exist? So it is a guideline by the METHOD that you assume unstated things dont exist? Will you pleas help quickly? 
Thanks a ton ;=)

Comment: I think I got it. It is because you need to SOLVE the word problem, which is only possible if you make certain assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** The question states nothing regarding whether or not there is a giant pink elephant inside the balloon that magically removes the air at a rate of 2 cubic feet per minute. Yet, you probably assume that there is no such elephant? **Why?**

In the same way, since the assignment says *nothing* about a leak, we assume that there is no such leak. A good way to think about this thing is to recognize that mathematical problems usually take place in an *ideal* world, hence the balloon is spherical (which, in reality, they aren't). The *ideal* balloon of course has no leak, unless specified in the assignment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. My only regard is that, when you say 
"In the same way, since the assignment says nothing about a leak, we assume that there is no such leak."

What is the REASON why you assume there is no leak? Is it axiomatic in that you assume there is no leak for no real reason? 

Thanks =)

Comment: @Aakarsh As I point out in the answer, a balloon in an ideal world has no leak. Always assume things to be "perfect", unless stated otherwise.

Comment: What is your definition of "perfect" here?

Comment: @Aakarsh The word i used earlier, ideal, is better. From wiktionary: " Optimal; being the best possibility."

Comment: @Aakarsh Can you give an explanation as to why you don't consider the pink elephant?

Comment: That is a very good point; I **CANT** actually answer that. Perhaps (and agree or disagree with me) it is because it is a possible accepted fact based on experience of how word problems are. The experience from the examples that all that exists is the given. What do you think about this?

Comment: @Aakarsh Is there a difference between your experience of balloons and your experience of balloons in word problems? Whenever I have a balloon, i don't expect it to have an elephant inside, just as i don't expect it to have a leak. And so, when I read about the balloon in your word problem, I don't expect it to have those things either.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks; That I understand very well; what I was asking was that, do you perhaps use your knowledge of word problems from what you were first taught? What about your knowledge/experience from the examples that nothing besides the stated/given exists? Thanks

Comment: @Aaakarsh I don't understand the question, sorry.

Comment: Im sorry =( I was asking you, before I ever asked this question, when YOU used to do word problems yourself, what was your PERSONAL reason behind accepting the fact that unstated items dont exist? Did you really blindly accept this fact? Thanks

Comment: @Aakarsh I did not blindly accept it, but I agree with it. There is no other way to do word problems, since there are infinitely many things that are not mentioned.

Comment: thanks ;) 

Would you agree with me if I said "this is a ACCEPTED METHOD in solving problems; the method being you remove unstated things" Do you think it is right to call this a METHOD rather than anything else? 
Thanks =)

Comment: @Aakarsh It's an interesting philosophical discussion, but I really don't understand why you are refusing to accept this. I would not say it is "a method", but part of "the method", whatever it is. What would you otherwise consider to be an alternative? Consider *all* things, stated and unstated? You would never finish a single problem in that way.

Comment: Hi
One question how is this philosophical? 
So in the end, you just have to accept this.There is no actual 100% perfect reason though correct? Its just a fact most people accept NOT HAVING A REASON. I dont recall asking this, but when you are doing word problems you just accept this fact without thinking of a reason correct? 

(question 2) By method, I meant you know how textbooks TEACH YOU **HOW TO SOLVE A WORD PROBLEM** they include this fact as a specific step. So I wondered if this is simply a method. Any idea on this?

I really appreciate your help @naslundx. Thankyou very much;thanks

Comment: After a long break of this, I think I got it. When you said "there is no other way to do word problems," it gave me a great idea. You make assumptions so that you **can SOLVE** a word problem. You must assume the word problem is solvable. This can be found by the wording "find....." so you know it is solvable. **Thanks again @naslundx**

Answer (score 1):

How do you know the material of the balloon will continue to hold until it reaches a radius of two feet?

How do you know the pump doesn't fail before that point?

How do you know there isn't a mischievous little kid waiting to poke the balloon with a needle before it reaches that point?

etc. etc.

These are all implicit assumptions. Not every possibility can be explicitly stated. There is no reason to presuppose a leak when it's not even been hinted at by the question.

Actually, a MUCH more obvious assumption in this question is that the balloon is a perfect sphere. If you think just a little about it, it's almost impossibly practical to have a "real-life" balloon that remains a perfect sphere throughout filling. For one thing, there has to be an inlet for the air that stretches uniformly while maintaining a perfect seal around the pump nozzle, which implies that the pump nozzle itself has to be expanding to fill the hole. Again, this is an assumption that one makes for simplicity. The question would become very difficult to handle if you tried analyzing a realistic balloon.

Comment: Hi,

When you say "There is no reason to presuppose a leak when it's not even been hinted at by the question."

Keep in mind that there is no reason to suppose the ABSENCE OF A LEAK, since thats also not hinted by the question.